# SFDX VSCode Unable to Authorize an Org

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I've been working using VSCode to develop Lightning Web Components for over 6 months, however today after restarting my machine I am unable to authorize my org. It was able to redirect me to the login page, and after I successfully log in to my org an error is thrown.

Command:

```
13:35:57.363 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias SME --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

Response:

```
ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  Parse error in file C:\Users\NSDO\.sfdx\alias.json on line 1
13:37:10.766 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias SME --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1
```

Before all that on the 30th of March I noticed that VSCode was updated to the Feb 2020 version and I suspect that this could have something to do with it. However, I have tried updating sfdx to 7.53 (previously from 7.52) and even uninstalled and re-installed VSCode (back to Oct 2019 version which I have been using) but this error is still there. Also that .sfdx\alias.json file is nowhere to be found.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to locate the alias.json file and to my surprise the json file contains non-human readable values like this:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000`

I'm still not sure who or what changed this file, but after changing it back to something like this it worked:

`{
    "orgs": {
        "sandbox": "sandbox@username.com"
    }
}`